# making two css classes equal

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

The Second following code makes two tabs. It has generated by a module. The module uses its own css classes to style it's own generated codes. There are other css classes that styles the tabs better than what the mentioned module does.(like bootstrap "nav" and "nav-tabs" classes). I want to make classes "tabs" equal to "nav nav-tabs". In other word I want to make `<ul class="tabs">` equal to `<ul class='nav nav-tabs'>`. I have searched a lot but no solution found. Copying css property from bootstrap and overriding "tabs" class seems inefficient. Is there an efficient way to do that? SomeThing like below code in html:

```
<style>
    .tabs{
    .nav;
    .navtabs;
    }
</style>
```

> note: I do not want to change the module css files or change Bootstrap css files.

```
<!-- Module generated code -->
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li>
        <a href="#">tab1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">tab2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tabs").addClass("nav navtabs");     
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can do it in one call, `$( '.tabs' ).addClass( 'nav nav-tabs' );`

Comment: Thank U. It works. How can I remove class??? :D :D. For example remove `.tabs` and add `.nav` and `.nav-tabs`??

Comment: @ManManam please do a little homework, [jQuery removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/).

Comment: To remove class with jquery : `$(".tabs").removeClass("nav navtabs");`

Comment: You can chain the methods, `$( '.tabs' ).removeClass( 'tabs' ).addClass( 'nav navtabs' );`.

Comment: Thank U all. I love This site!!

Answer (score 0):

use LESS for this.

```
<style>
    .tabs{
         // your css here. 
         // and the calss which you want to inherit this property.     
    } 
</style>
```

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T2Xe9/) here

Comment: So I have to copy the property of .nav and .nav-tabs classes from bootstrap css file there...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I mentioned that this solution seems inefficient.

Comment: ok i didnt see that. in this case use `LESS`. It will be helpful.